# solr lucene apply bf only when query matches text

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

when query "email from john" matches text "some other text that has email from john" and each word in query exists in text field in this exact format:

then and only then I need to apply bf function.

Is it possible to achieve this rule/functionality with Solr ?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Not that I am aware of. What application layer do you have from where you use Solr? e.g. When having a Java client (using Solrj) it would be very easy to add a bf in case some text is contained in the query ...

Comment: @cheffe I am calling Solr from cms system called CQ5. Could you provide a simple example of how you would do it with Solrj ?

Comment: why not use phrase boosting ? it is very close to what you need to do the only difference is that in phrase boosting the words must appear in the same order. You just need to specify the pf parameter with the names of fields and weight for each field.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, you just need to make a new request handler in your solrconfig.xml that applies that function:

```
<requestHandler name="/match" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="rows">5</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="bf">product(log(sum(popularity,1)),100)^20</str>
    <str name="boost">product(map(query($type1query),0,0,1,$type1boost),map(query($type2query),0,0,1,$type2boost),map(query($type3query),0,0,1,$type3boost),map(query($type4query),0,0,1,$type4boost),$typeboost)</str>
    <double name="typeboost">1.0</double>

    <str name="type1query">type:"type1"</str>
    <double name="type1boost">0.9</double>
    <str name="type2query">type:"type2"</str>
    <double name="type2boost">0.5</double>
    <str name="type3query">type:"type3"</str>
    <double name="type3boost">0.3</double>
    <str name="type4query">type:"type4"</str>
    <double name="type4boost">0.1</double>
    <str name="debugQuery">false</str>
    <str name="omitHeader">true</str> 
    <str name="wt">json</str> 
    <str name="indent">true</str> 
</lst>
```

And build a query that will only match those words like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/match?q=*email from john
```